# ROS & boost 1.47

Tags: boost, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, did anyone try to build ROS with boost 1.47 yet? I get some errors. 1.46.1 works fine. ROS seems to use some pretty specific stuff. :).

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:133: error: no type named ‘reference’ in ‘class boost::transform_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::copy_iterator_rangeF<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, boost::algorithm::split_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, boost::use_default, boost::use_default>’
  /opt/local/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_destructor.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::has_trivial_destructor<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >’:
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:911:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from ‘boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::function2(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:51:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::detail::find_iterator_base<IteratorT>::find_iterator_base(FinderT, int) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:260:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::split_iterator<IteratorT>::split_iterator(IteratorT, IteratorT, FinderT) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:171:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::iter_split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, FinderT) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, RangeT = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:149:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, PredicateT, boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type) [with SequenceSequenceT = ros::package::V_string, RangeT = std::string, PredicateT = boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>]’
  /Users/mriedel/MPI/CrossCompiling/Source/ros_armv6/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:75:   instantiated from here
  /opt/local/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_destructor.hpp:36: error: ‘boost::detail::has_trivial_dtor_impl<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >::value’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘bool’ because it is a non-constant expression
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’:
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from ‘boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::function2(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:51:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::detail::find_iterator_base<IteratorT>::find_iterator_base(FinderT, int) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:260:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::split_iterator<IteratorT>::split_iterator(IteratorT, IteratorT, FinderT) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:171:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::iter_split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, FinderT) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, RangeT = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:149:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, PredicateT, boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type) [with SequenceSequenceT = ros::package::V_string, RangeT = std::string, PredicateT = boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>]’
  /Users/mriedel/MPI/CrossCompiling/Source/ros_armv6/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:75:   instantiated from here
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:911: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘boost::has_trivial_destructor<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >’
  /opt/local/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_copy.hpp: At global scope:
  /opt/local/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_copy.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::has_trivial_copy_constructor<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >’:
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:911:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from ‘boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::function2(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:51:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::detail::find_iterator_base<IteratorT>::find_iterator_base(FinderT, int) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:260:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::split_iterator<IteratorT>::split_iterator(IteratorT, IteratorT, FinderT) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:171:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::iter_split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, FinderT) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, RangeT = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:149:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, PredicateT, boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type) [with SequenceSequenceT = ros::package::V_string, RangeT = std::string, PredicateT = boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>]’
  /Users/mriedel/MPI/CrossCompiling/Source/ros_armv6/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:75:   instantiated from here
  /opt/local/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_copy.hpp:43: error: ‘boost::detail::has_trivial_copy_impl<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >::value’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘bool’ because it is a non-constant expression
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’:
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from ‘boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::function2(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, R = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:51:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::detail::find_iterator_base<IteratorT>::find_iterator_base(FinderT, int) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:260:   instantiated from ‘boost::algorithm::split_iterator<IteratorT>::split_iterator(IteratorT, IteratorT, FinderT) [with FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >, IteratorT = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:171:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::iter_split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, FinderT) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, RangeT = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> >]’
  /opt/local/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:149:   instantiated from ‘SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, PredicateT, boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type) [with SequenceSequenceT = ros::package::V_string, RangeT = std::string, PredicateT = boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>]’
  /Users/mriedel/MPI/CrossCompiling/Source/ros_armv6/ros/core/roslib/src/package.cpp:75:   instantiated from here
  /opt/local/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:911: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘boost::has_trivial_copy_constructor<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char> > >’
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10599/ros-&-boost-1.47/) by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given the lack of answers, I'm guessing that the answer is "no, at the time you asked, people have not used 1.47 with ROS".  Patches for 1.47 compatibility are always welcome.

closing this question out.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0